# Bash String parameter white space truncation

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written a script to send messages to users after reading them from the file.

```
i.e. ./sendxms number " TEST MSG" -P AccountID -O ID
```

All parameters are read except message which is truncated after first space

```
i.e. ./sendxms 123232 "TEST" -P AccountID -O ID
```

Message is truncated after first word below is my script please help

```
#!/bin/bash
  cd /usr/local/SendXMS
  echo "nohup ./sendxms -q1 -aRECEIVE &"
  cd /var/mk/Ali_Test
  echo enter file name
  read fname
  exec<$fname
  OLD_IFS=$IFS
  count=0
  while read line 
   do
       count=`expr $count + 1`;
       IFS=' '
       read var1 var2 <<<"$line"
       #echo "$var1"
       #echo "$line"
       string="\"This is a test message $var2.\""
       cd /usr/local/SendXMS
       ./sendxms +$var1 $string -pSMPP -Otest
       cd /var/mk/Ali_Test
       sleep 1

   done
   IFS=$OLD_IFS
   echo "Total SMS Sent $count";
```

Comment: I don't even see where this script is using its commandline arguments; where is e. g. `$1`?

Comment: I was not using commandline arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is due to the fact that you aren't quoting arguments in command line here:

```
./sendxms +$var1 $string -pSMPP -Otest
```

Change that to:

```
./sendxms +"$var1" "$string" -pSMPP -Otest
```